# Proof that $(u+v)^p = u^p + v^p$ in vector space over finite field of characteristic $p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb F_q$ with $q = p^n$ a finite field of characteristic $p$. Then for all $x,y \in \mathbb F_q$ we have $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$. If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_q$-vector space of dimension $n$, then I want to proof that for all $u,v \in V$ we have
$$
 (u + v)^p = u^p + v^p
$$
where $u^p := u + \ldots + u$ ($p$-times) by definition. I know as $V \cong \mathbb F_q^n$ then this holds by "computing in the coordinates", but is there a proof without resorting to coordinates, i.e. computing in $\mathbb F_q^n$?

Comment: The only times I've seen exponential notation for multiplication by scalars is when the original vector space or module operation is written multiplicatively. I don't see the utility in mixing them up. Anyway, both sides are zero, since adding $1$ to itself $p$ times yields $0$ in any ring of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Of course it is true for every $n\in \mathbb N$ if you define $u^p$ like that... this is just a really awkward notation for a particular instance of distributivity $p\cdot (x+y)=p\cdot x + p\cdot y$. The "problem" is that it does _not_ specialize to the known identity $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ in the case the dimension is $1$ because there $u^p$ means something different.

Comment: Yes. I somehow was confused and mixed it up, I wanted to ask why $u^p = 0$ and $p$ is the smallest such number in the vector space. Normally this kind of addtion is written as $n \cdot x := x + \ldots + x$ ($n$ times) as the abelian group of a vector space is a $\mathbb Z$-module over itself. Anyway, as I got a lot of great answers I let this question stand as it is.

Comment: If $M$ is an $R$-module then it has an underlying additive abelian group which makes $M$ also a $\Bbb Z$-module. If $R$ is unital, there is a (unique, unital) ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to R$ (what is the map?), and that also makes $M$ into a $\Bbb Z$-module. In fact these are both the same $\Bbb Z$-module structure on $M$. If you know what "module" means, try to prove this, and determine its relevance.

Comment: Let $M$ be an $R$-module, define $n \cdot x := x + \ldots + x$ ($n$ times), this makes $M$ a $\mathbb Z$-module. Now suppose $\varphi : Z \to R$ is a unital ring homomorphism, then the requirements $\varphi(1) = 1, \varphi(n+1) = \varphi(n) + \varphi(1) = \varphi(n) + 1$ and $\varphi(-n) = -\varphi(n)$ give inductively that $\varphi(n) = 1 + \ldots + 1$ ($n$ times). By setting $n \cdot x := \varphi(n) \cdot x$ this gives also $\mathbb Z$-module structure on $M$, and be the above computations it equals the first defined $\mathbb Z$-module structure. But for what its good, I do not know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because addition is commutative,
$$(u+v)^p=\underbrace{(u+v)+\cdots+(u+v)}_p=\underbrace{u+\cdots+u}_p+\underbrace{v+\cdots+v}_p=u^p+v^p$$

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic of the field is $p$, so we have $a^p=0$ for every element $a$ with the given definition. This immediately implies the given equation.

Comment: I meant it for vectors, not elements of the field.

Answer (score 2):

It's true even for vectors $v \in V$ over $\Bbb F_q$: $v^p = \underbrace {v + \dots + v} _ {p \ \text{times}} = (\underbrace {1 + \dots + 1} _ {p \ \text{times}}) \cdot v = 0 \cdot v = 0$.

In fact, this shows not only that $(u+v)^p = u^p + v^p$, but that the equality is trivially true, each term of it being $0$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, that answered the question I had in mind. But as I had it written differently I have to accept the other answer which answers the question I actually wrote up.